# Client Hanging Error in TCP

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, client

I am using python to stream data and I am trying to copy the data read in to a text file. The code I am using works fine once though I need this to continually loop. I thought the while loop should do this but the output just hangs. Where am I going wrong?

```
import socket
import sys
import time

#Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


#bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('192.168.1.90', 10000)
print >> sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)

while True:

try:
    #send data
    message = 'Making Connection . . .'
    print >> sys.stderr, '"%s"' % message
    sock.sendall(message)

    #look for response
    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = 4096

    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = sock.recv(4096)
            amount_received += len(data)
        print >> sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
    with open ('SPI.txt', 'a') as output:
            output.write(data)
    time.sleep(0.5)

finally:
       print >> sys.stderr, 'closing socket'
       sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

sock.recv is a blocking call, it will return only if there is any data available for read. You need to use a different thread to recv the data on socket or use non-blocking sockets.